# Как сделать привязку x:Bind StackPanel к GridView

Tags: c#, uwp

GridView отображает на странице данные из коллекции объектов:

```
private ObservableCollection<Monitoring> Monitorings; 

public class Monitoring
{
    // Свойства
    public int Code_Order { get; set; }         
    public int Code_Client { get; set; }                
    public string FullName_Client { get; set; } 
    public int Code_BP { get; set; }            
    public int Code_Model { get; set; }         
    public string ModelIcon { get; set; }         
    public AssemblyTechnology Technology { get; set; }          
    public string TechnologyIcon { get; set; }             
    public StackPanel Bar;
}

<GridView x:Name="gvMonitoring" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="gvMonitoring_ItemClick">
    <GridView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Width="60" Text="Код зак."/>
                <TextBlock Width="60" Text="Код кл."/>
                <TextBlock Width="220" Text="ФИО клиента"/>
                <TextBlock Width="60" Text="Код БП"/>
                <TextBlock Width="60" Text="Код модели"/>
                <TextBlock Width="38" Text=""/>
                <TextBlock Width="150" Text="Технология сборки"/>
                <TextBlock Width="400" Text="Выполнение операций"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.HeaderTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Monitoring">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Width="60" Text="{x:Bind Code_Order}"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Width="60" Text="{x:Bind Code_Client}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="220" Text="{x:Bind FullName_Client}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="60" Text="{x:Bind Code_BP}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="60" Text="{x:Bind Code_Model}"/>
                <Image Width="38" Height="38" Source="{x:Bind ModelIcon}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="150" Text="{x:Bind Technology}"/>
                <StackPanel Width="400" DataContext="{x:Bind Bar}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

При этом свойство Bar представляет из себя объект StackPanel, содержащий несколько кнопок.
Подскажите, как сделать привязку x:Bind этого свойства к GridView. Так как показано в тексте программы не работает, StackPanel не отображается в UI, хотя ни какой ошибки не возникает.

Comment: Используйте сочетание Ctrl+K для форматирования кода в вопросе.

Comment: Ого, а почему вы храните контролы UWP в модели? А если завтра вы заходите отображать данные не в UWP-приложении, а в веб-приложении? Что делать?

Comment: Ну а вообще, если не обращать внимание на то что я написал выше, то должно сработать так: `<ContentControl Width="400" Content="{x:Bind Bar}"/>`

Comment: Спасибо, так работает нормально. Веб-приложение для этой программы не планируется, поэтому так сделал. Там сложный контрол, который собирается из более 20 кнопок. Он выполняет функцию индикатора (установкой кнопок в соответствующий цвет) и одновременно при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку вызывается вывод аналитики по этой кнопке

Comment: В любом случае это так не делается, выносите сложный контрол в UserControl, а в модели пусть лежат только данные предметной области